# Nodejs : Get zip file from aws s3 url and manipulate files inside it after extracting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch a zip file uploaded to aws s3. After that file is fetched, I have to extract it and display the names of files inside the folder. How can I achieve this?  I am new to file streaming and this is what I have done till now.

```js
import * as aws from "aws-sdk";
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";
import request from "request";
import * as unzipper from "unzipper";

const config = {
  // credentials
};

const s3Client = new aws.S3(config);
const app = express();

app.use(express.json({
  limit: "1mb"
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post("/seturl", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = req.body.url;
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ez.zip'));
    console.log("here");
    const zip = fs.createReadStream('ez.zip').pipe(unzipper.Parse({
      forceStream: true
    }));
    for await (const entry of zip) {
      const fileName = entry.path;
      console.log("///////////", fileName);
      const type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
      const size = entry.vars.uncompressedSize; // There is also compressedSize;
      if (fileName === "this IS the file I'm looking for") {
        entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/path'));
      } else {
        entry.autodrain();
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(`Error in reading ${error}`);
  }
});

app.listen(5600, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("running");
  }
});
```

I am using the unzipper library here. If there is something better, I am open to use it. As of now, I am getting FILE ENDED error.

Comment: Can you write full error stack trace?What else does it say?

Comment: @LazarNikolic FILE ENDED is the only thing it says. I'm getting `running` and `here` in console, after that it says `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error in reading Error: FILE_ENDED`.

Comment: @Gabriel Did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm facing the exact same issue (streaming a zip file from S3 to `unzipper`)